# Как запустить JavaScript код из iframe в index.html(Основное окно)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, iframe

Я не понимаю как это реализовать, у меня ничего не получилось. Сперва я хотел использовать contentWindow
но оно у меня не работает, потом через некоторое время я увидел что это можно как через easyXDM сделать
но и это я тоже не смог пожалуйста помогите с этой проблемой.
Желательно с easyXDM.
[Cсылка на код index и iframe страниц](https://pastebin.com/bucbLjnD)

в общем мне нужно запустить javascript код из iframe чтобы оно изменило свойства CSS div с id=by1

Comment: Что-то я не могу получить доступ к вашему коду на pastebin

Comment: Исправил теперь можете зайти на pastebin. Вроде теперь должно работать

Comment: Вообще, изменение iframe родительским окном и наоборот скажем так нарушает безопасность. Браузер просто не даст вам провернуть подобное